# How to hide Shell Item on Flyout

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project in which I have a ShellItem `login` and then it shows me a FlyoutItem `main` with different tabs.

Here is the code on my `AppShell`

```
<ShellItem Route="login" x:Name="loginItem">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
    </ShellItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Route="main" Icon="homepage.png" >
        
            <Tab Icon="search.png">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CategoryPage}" />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Route="CartPage" Icon="shopping_cart.png">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CartPage}" />
            </Tab>
            <Tab Route="InvoicePage" Icon="invoice.png">
                <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:InvoicePage}" />
            </Tab>
       
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Información" Icon="information.png">
        <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:InfoPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Contacto" Icon="contact.png">
        <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ContactSupportPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
```

Here is the login page, as you can see I don't want to display the flyout item yet.

[image]

The issue is on my FlyoutItem "main". If the user accidentally presses the blank space above "Home" it will take them to the login page which I don't want to happen.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way of hiding that FlyoutItem? I thought it wouldn't show as I have not added it as a FlyoutItem to my AppShell.

Please help and thanks.

Comment: Have you tryed  FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<ShellItem Route="login" x:Name="loginItem" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" >
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
</ShellItem>
```

Docs :

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-visibility